# Do you recommend Visual Studio 11 Beta as a production?

Tags: visual-studio

I want to ask other developers about Visual Studio 11.

I'm currently using VS2010 SP1 and some components like DevExpress. All of them is compatible with VS11.

In my situation, i am able to handle all errors during this beta period and i can accept that. But, to be more clear, to deploy my outputs (exe/dll .NET 4.0) to other machines (like customers) do you recommend to use of Visual Studio 11?

Is there any limitation(s) or other things on VS11 and/or deployed / build outputs?

I know, it is BETA but in BETA stage is it safe to use it as a default IDE instead of VS2010.

If I use VS11 I will probably still use .NET 4.0 but not 4.5 Beta.

I liked the new things and IDE interface style of VS11 so its attract me -very much-.

More importantly, do you use it on production?

Comment: @vikki refer the below comment.@BNL why? I mean i can understand its beta but for targeting  .NET 4.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm currently using it as a production tool but **only** when targeting .Net 4.0 and below.  So far I have not found any issues.  I wouldn't recommend it for a production environment if you are compiling against .Net 4.5.

Microsoft however does offer production support. You can read more about it here:

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/downloads/go-live

Hope it helps!

Comment: Getting support for production use is exactly for me. Why i didn't see it before :) Research research research... Thanks! Edit: Microsoft will probably reject my request due to targeting .NET 4.0. They only support / cover .NET 4.5 production only. (it seems) But i will give it a chance. Otherwise, i will going to acept your answer if no more answer(s) comes out.

Comment: Thanks for the clearification about production that targets .NET 4.0. Your answer is enough to go. Answer is accepted.